# flowWithLifecycle(lifecycle, Lifecycle.State.STARTED) doesn't stop flows while App is in background

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow, kotlin-stateflow

I'm trying to observe the result of the ***View Collection and upstream flows stopped***.
But `viewModel.testFlow` is still collecting while the App is in the background.
Why can't I observe the collection is stopped? Am I observing something wrong?

ViewModel:

```
val testFlow = flow<Int> {
    for (i in 1..100) {
        delay(1000)
        Timber.e("testFlow: EMIT = $i")
        emit(i)
    }
}
```

Activity:

```
override fun onViewCreated() {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewModel.testFlow
                .flowWithLifecycle(lifecycle, Lifecycle.State.STARTED)
                .collect {
                    Timber.d("testFlow: $it Collected")
                }
        }
}

override fun onActivityPaused(activity: Activity) {
    super.onActivityPaused(activity)
    Timber.e("testFlow: onActivityPaused")
}
```

[image: Logs]
[image: Lifecycle Diagram]

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/a-safer-way-to-collect-flows-from-android-uis-23080b1f8bda

Comment: Where did you get the `lifecycle` variable for your flowWithLifecycle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `Lifecycle.State.STARTED` state to start observing `Flow`, the corresponding method of the `Activity` when emission stops is `onStop()`. If `onStop()` method of `Activity` is called the emission and collecting will stop.

If you want to stop emitting and collection data when `onPause` method is called, you can use `Lifecycle.State.RESUMED` state.

When app goes to background `onStop()` method of `Activity` is called and when using `Lifecycle.State.STARTED` state to observe the `Flow` you should see the emission and collecting stop.

Answer (score 0):

you can handle another way with repeatOnLifecycle

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
        repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED){
            viewModel.stateLocationPermission.collect() {
                handleStateLocationPermission(it)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of this extension:

```kotlin
fun <T> Flow<T>.collectLifecycleAware(
    owner: LifecycleOwner,
    flowCollector: FlowCollector<T>,
) {
    owner.lifecycleScope.launch {
        this@collectLifecycleAware.flowWithLifecycle(owner.lifecycle)
            .collect(flowCollector)
    }
}
```

And use it as:

```kotlin
state.collectLifecycleAware(viewLifecycleOwner) { state ->
    ...
}
```

Also, you'll need:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:<latest-version>"
```